Set numpy printoptions based on bit-width/specific int dtype in a single print statement
I'm working with a lot of binary data, where my data can be a mix of bit-widths.
I want to print or log my data correctly formatted by bit-width, all in a single statement.
Simple example showing only 16 and 32 bit data:
import numpy as np

numbers_32_bit = np.array((0x1000_0000, 0x2000_0000, 0x3000_0000, 0x4000_0000),dtype=np.uint32)
numbers_16_bit = np.array((0x5000, 0x6000, 0x7000, 0x8000), dtype=np.uint16)

np_formatter = {
    # Doesn't throw an error, but has no effect, as expected as per numpy docs
    "uint32": lambda x: f"{x:08X}",
    "uint16": lambda x: f"{x:04X}",
    
    # Applies to all ints
    "int": lambda x: f"0x{x:08X}"
}

np.set_printoptions(formatter=np_formatter)
print(f"32 bits: {numbers_32_bit}, 16 bits: {numbers_16_bit}")

Print output:
32 bits: [0x10000000 0x20000000 0x30000000 0x40000000], 16 bits: [0x00005000 0x00006000 0x00007000 0x00008000]

As you can see, the 16 bit numbers still have the 32-bit formatter applied, as it uses the int formatter, rather than uint16.
This works on a statement-by-statement basis, but isn't great when you have lots of print/log statements throughout a project:
def format_bitwidths(n8=0, n16=0, n32=0, n64=0):
    np.set_printoptions(formatter={"int": lambda x: f"0x{x:02X}"})
    s8 = f"{n8}"
    np.set_printoptions(formatter={"int": lambda x: f"0x{x:04X}"})
    s16 = f"{n16}"
    np.set_printoptions(formatter={"int": lambda x: f"0x{x:08X}"})
    s32 = f"{n32}"
    np.set_printoptions(formatter={"int": lambda x: f"0x{x:016X}"})
    s64 = f"{n64}"
    return s8, s16, s32, s64


_, str_16_bits, str_32_bits, _ = format_bitwidths(n16=numbers_16_bit, n32=numbers_32_bit)
print(f"32 bits: {str_32_bits}, 16 bits: {str_16_bits}")

Print output:
32 bits: [0x10000000 0x20000000 0x30000000 0x40000000], 16 bits: [0x5000 0x6000 0x7000 0x8000]

Is there a way to set this once without having to call np.set_printoptions or format_bitwidths before each print/log?
If not, is there some other method which I can set once, and apply it across an entire script?

It looks like the uint32 and uint16 entries are simply ignored. If you leave out the int entry, you don't get any custom formatting.

Other than the fmt function is "sticky", this is an option:
import numpy as np

n8 = np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.uint8)
n16 = np.array((0x5000, 0x6000, 0x7000, 0x8000), dtype=np.uint16)
n64 = np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.uint64)
n32 = np.array((0x1000_0000, 0x2000_0000, 0x3000_0000, 0x4000_0000),dtype=np.uint32)

def fmt(arr):
    match arr.dtype.name:
        case 'uint8':
            np.set_printoptions(formatter={'int': lambda x: f'0x{x:02X}'})
        case 'uint16':
            np.set_printoptions(formatter={'int': lambda x: f'0x{x:04X}'})
        case 'uint32':
            np.set_printoptions(formatter={'int': lambda x: f'0x{x:08X}'})
        case 'uint64':
            np.set_printoptions(formatter={'int': lambda x: f'0x{x:016X}'})
    return arr

print(f' 8 bits: {fmt(n8)}\n16 bits: {fmt(n16)}\n32 bits: {fmt(n32)}\n64 bits: {fmt(n64)}')

Output:
 8 bits: [0x01 0x02 0x03]
16 bits: [0x5000 0x6000 0x7000 0x8000]
32 bits: [0x10000000 0x20000000 0x30000000 0x40000000]
64 bits: [0x0000000000000001 0x0000000000000002 0x0000000000000003]


Thanks, this is much better than what I was trying to do with format_bitwidths.
